# python changing the numerical values of a string based on calculations within its own string

Tags: python, pandas, string

I'm working with a dataframe with medicinal products and I have to extract the dosage out of the name (string), and later change the original product name with the reduced form of the dosage.

Example of what I have:

```
Name
'Prenoxad 2mg/2ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes'
```

I want to have, stored in a new column:

```
Name_reduced
'Prenoxad 1mg/ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes'
```

Another example is having `250mg/5ml`, and wanting to have `50mg/ml`.

I want to do this for every product in the dataframe that needs to have its dosage reduced. Not all products have the dosage in their name, and also some products have different dosages in their name that don't need any reduction, for example:

`Co-amoxiclav 250mg/125mg tablets`

So I think the best way to do this might be to only apply the reduction method on products containing `'/'`, `'mg'` and `'ml'`, since this reduction only needs to happen when `'mg'` and `'ml'` are present. And also for products that don't have the exact string `'mg/ml'` in their name, as it only happens for the dosages already in their reduced form.

I can extract the section of the string that I want to use like this:

```
txt = "Prenoxad 2mg/2ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes"
x = re.findall("\d.+/*\d.{2}",txt)
print(x)

#['2mg/2ml']
```

But I don't know what to do after this, what is the best way to do this 'reduction' method?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
import re
txt = "Prenoxad 2mg/2ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes"
x = re.findall("\d.+/*\d.{2}",txt)[0]
items = ['mg', 'ml', '/']
if all([item in x for item in items]):
    mg, ml = re.findall(r"(\d+)",txt)
    ratio = float(mg)/float(ml)
    txt.replace(x, f'{ratio}mg/ml')
txt
```

Output:

```
'Prenoxad 1.0mg/ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a DataFrame as input, you can use a custom function with `str.replace`:

```
def simplify(m):
    q1, u1, q2, u2 = m.groups()
    q1, q2 = int(q1), int(q2)
    if set([u1,u2])>{'mg', 'ml'}:
        return f'{q1}{u1}/{q2}{u2}'
    else:
        q = q1/q2
        if int(q) == q:
            q = int(q)
        return f'{q}{u1}/{u2}'
        
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('(\d+)(..)/(\d+)(..)', simplify, regex=True)
```

output (as Name2 column for comparison):

```
                        Name                     Name2
0  Prenoxad 2mg/2ml solution  Prenoxad 1mg/ml solution
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Prenoxad 2mg/2ml solution']})
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need the function that properly processes you text:

```
def reduce_name(txt):
    re_digits = '(\d+)mg/(\d+)ml'
    x = re.findall(re_digits,txt)
    if len(x) > 0:
        reduced_value = int(x[0][0]) // int(x[0][1])
        reduced_txt = re.sub(re_digits, f'{reduced_value}mg/ml', txt)
        return reduced_txt
    else:
        return txt
```

And if you want to apply in to the entire column, you can do it like this:

```
df['column_name'].apply(reduce_name)
```

Please pay attention to the possible specific cases and adjust the code accordingly:

- сheck if numeric values can contain thousands separators, e.g. 2,500mg/...
- сheck if spaces can appear inside a regular expression
- сheck if the first value is always divisible by the second without remainder

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fractions` module to reduce the ratios. Then, you can use `re.sub` with a `lambda` to find the ratio and replace it.

```
import re
from fractions import Fraction

def replace_ratio(ratio):
    fraction = Fraction(int(ratio.group(1)), int(ratio.group(2)))
    numerator = fraction.numerator
    denominator = "" if fraction.denominator == 1 else fraction.denominator
    return f"{numerator}ml/{denominator}mg"

def process_text(text):
    return re.sub("(\d+)mg/(\d+)ml", lambda ratio: replace_ratio(ratio), text)

print(process_text("Prenoxad 2mg/2ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes")) 
# -> Prenoxad 1ml/mg solution for injection pre-filled syringes

print(process_text("Prenoxad 10mg/3ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes"))
# -> Prenoxad 10ml/3mg solution for injection pre-filled syringes

print(process_text("Prenoxad 120mg/6ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes"))
# -> Prenoxad 20ml/mg solution for injection pre-filled syringes
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used this and seemed to work fine, but I came across some problems:


1. `Oxybutynin 2.5mg/5ml oral solution sugar free` is transformed into `'Oxybutynin 2.1mg/ml oral solution sugar free'`, because instead of recognizing '2.5', it only extracts the number(s) after the '.'


2. There are cases where the dosage of 2 substances is in the name: `'Co-amoxiclav 250mg/62mg/5ml oral suspension sugar free'`. For these cases, I don't want any reduction to occur.


How can I address these problems?

Comment: @PedroDomingues can you explain the second case a bit more? I don't exactly understand what the different amounts are.

Comment: in this specific case, `'Co-amoxiclav 250mg/62mg/5ml oral suspension sugar free'` means that 5 ml reconstituted suspension contain 250 mg of amoxicillin and 62 mg of clavulanic acid. For this particular product the function doesn't do anything, but if the product was named `'Co-amoxiclav 250mg/60mg/5ml oral suspension sugar free'` it would return `'Co-amoxiclav 250mg/12mg/ml oral suspension sugar free'`, and that could happen for some products. To avoid these problems, the best option would be to not apply any reduction for products with more than one dosage.