# Parsing fractions with Python

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe with medicinal products and I have to extract the dosage out of the name (string), and later change the original product name with the reduced form of the dosage.

Example of what I have:

```
Name
'Prenoxad 2mg/2ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes'
```

I want to have, stored in a new column:

```
Name_reduced
'Prenoxad 1mg/ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes'
```

I asked for help doing this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71940457/python-changing-the-numerical-values-of-a-string-based-on-calculations-within-it), and got:

```
import re
from fractions import Fraction

def replace_ratio(ratio):
    fraction = Fraction(int(ratio.group(1)), int(ratio.group(2)))
    numerator = fraction.numerator
    denominator = "" if fraction.denominator == 1 else fraction.denominator
    return f"{numerator}ml/{denominator}mg"

def process_text(text):
    return re.sub("(\d+)mg/(\d+)ml", lambda ratio: replace_ratio(ratio), text)

print(process_text("Prenoxad 2mg/2ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes")) 
# -> Prenoxad 1ml/mg solution for injection pre-filled syringes

print(process_text("Prenoxad 10mg/3ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes"))
# -> Prenoxad 10ml/3mg solution for injection pre-filled syringes

print(process_text("Prenoxad 120mg/6ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes"))
# -> Prenoxad 20ml/mg solution for injection pre-filled syringes
```

This works pretty well except for very specific cases, such as:

1. Floats are not well dealt with:

`'Oxybutynin 2.5mg/5ml oral solution sugar free'` is transformed into `'Oxybutynin 2.1mg/ml oral solution sugar free'`

This happens because the algorithm only considers the decimal values of the float, instead of the whole float.

Ideally, the output should be `'Oxybutynin 2.5mg/5ml oral solution sugar free'`.

2. Some products have dosage information for more than one substance:

`'Co-amoxiclav 250mg/62mg/5ml oral suspension sugar free'` means that 5 ml reconstituted suspension contain 250 mg of amoxicillin and 62 mg of clavulanic acid. For this particular product the function outputs `'Co-amoxiclav 250mg/62mg/5ml oral suspension sugar free'`, but if the product was named `'Co-amoxiclav 250mg/60mg/5ml oral suspension sugar free'` it would return `'Co-amoxiclav 250mg/12mg/ml oral suspension sugar free'` because it only recognizes the last 2 values.

To solve this, maybe the best option is to create an exception that everytime the product has information for more than one substance (measured in `mg`), the function doesn't run over that product.

3. Last one is for the cases where there's a blank space:

```
print(process_text("Prenoxad 120mg/6ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes"))
#Prenoxad 20ml/mg solution for injection pre-filled syringes
```

```
print(process_text("Prenoxad 120mg /6ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes"))
#Prenoxad 120mg /6ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes
```

```
print(process_text("Prenoxad 120mg/ 6ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes"))
#Prenoxad 120mg/ 6ml solution for injection pre-filled syringes
```

How can I solve these 3 problems?

Comment: I also would advise changing the question topic to something like `"Parsing fractions with Python"`, which is not so abstract and is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Your task is all about parsing text and you are on the right way with regular expressions. But you should modify your regex a bit.

The expression `r"(\d+)mg/(\d+)ml"` is good, but it is not enough.

- To couple with whitespace you need to add `\s*`
- To couple with dots use `[\d\.]+` rather then just `\d+`
- So, modified regex should be something like `([\d\.]+)mg\s*/\s*([\d\.]+)ml`
- What about complicated portions - like `"1mg/1mg/1mg"`: in function
  `replace_ratio` you can check number of matches with `len(ratio)`

There is a nice site [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to debug regexes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the dots, `print(process_textvir("Imodium 10 mg / 2.5 ml oral solution"))` returns the error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.5'`. I think in this case I want it to simply skip when it finds a float, how can I do this? Regarding the complicated portions (as you named it), the modified regex will always have `len(ratio)=2`, so maybe I should first run everything with the modified regex you gave me and then run another which finds 3 groups and changes it back to the original expression.

Comment: The error with floats is because you parse `ration.group(1)` with `int` function, which parse only ints. You should parse it with `Decimal()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.
What about `len` - you need to get number of matches, not number of groups in match, which actually always 2

Comment: Or you can use some hack like just counting number of letter `'/'` in a query.